# Building managed package using JS frameworks/library

Tags: managed-package, security-review, angularjs, lightning-web-components, react

I'm trying to do an analysis of an existing managed package that we have built currently we have a bunch of VF pages and Lightning Components.

At end of this analysis, we want to determine which JS framework we should be using to build our application on (Angular/React) or it could be LWC.

My main concern at this point is will the managed package fail security review if I build applications on Angular or React?

Comment: You can view below question, it has a similar discussion: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262897/use-of-javascript-frameworks-in-lightning-web-component