# Is there any way to use Material Web Components in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way to include the web components externally developed like https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components
in Lighting web components.

Any points to where to get started if possible would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Kiran Machhewar

Comment: I don't think it will ever get to a point where you could do an `import` of the Material library. However, that doesn't stop you from saving the CSS libraries as static resources and then reproducing what is on the web tab in this demo https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/card

Comment: I think this is a better starting point https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web

Comment: I have used react, so it seems possible.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262897/use-of-javascript-frameworks-in-lightning-web-component

Comment: Thank you guys for providing interesting insights. Will try to keep this thread updated on what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 3rd party web components in LWC is not possible per this
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_custom_elements

> **Third-Party Web Components**
>   To prevent security risks, you can’t use third-party web components on the Salesforce platform.
>
> Web components are custom elements. To define a custom element, you
>   must use the customElements.define API. However, this API is global,
>   and allows you to globally register a component name. Registering a
>   name globally is a security risk because an attacker could register
>   any name and take over the page. Lightning Locker’s SecureWindow
>   wrapper blocks the customElements methods that create custom web
>   components.
>
> The SecureWindow wrapper list in the Locker API Viewer tool shows that
>   customElements is not supported.

Created the idea for the same https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PcvhQAC

Upvote the idea if you think having 3rd party web components in LWC is a good idea.

**Note:** Using react in LWC worked because it was not defining any web component.

Comment: Can you accept this answer to indicate the question is resolved?